# Javascript & jQuery escaping quotes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, escaping

I'm trying to do inline editing for my website using jQuery so I can edit the HTML and text of a page without having to change the source. When I submit the form data though jQuery's $.ajax function, it escapes all the quotes. How can I either prevent jQuery from escaping this(probably a bad idea) or remove them on the PHP side of things. I tired stripslashes...but that didn't do anything. I know it's jQuery because if I do htmlentities() before submitting the text to MySQL...the slashes are still added.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is almost always preferred to `htmlentities()` despite what Chris Shiflett says in his book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not jQuery that's [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/magic_quotes) in PHP. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting/520298#520298) how you can remove them.