# PHP Magic Quotes quick fix

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

My Magic_Quotes has always been on and only today I've seen it's becoming depriciated. If I have it off could I just escape all user input (whether it's being used in my database or not). I definitely can't go back and rewrite all my database queries to use mysql_real_escape_string().

Could I just loop through all my $_GET, $_POST and $_SESSION and apply mysql_real_escape_string() ?

Comment: Just so you know "depreciated" and "deprecated" are two different things. :)

Comment: I think it should rather be “I definitely *don’t want* go back and rewrite all my database queries”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` and `magic_quotes_gpc` are two different things. Magic quotes does not render your input safe enough for SQL queries.

Whether you like it or not, you **should** convert all your database queries to use a proper escaping mechanism, or you otherwise leave your application open to security issues like SQL injection.

You can't really apply `mysql_real_escape_string` directly on $_GET, $_POST, etc. because it might mess up your input data if you need it for anything else than SQL (like form validation and such).

Comment: In my case, it would probably be easier to fix the things it messes up rather than go back and recode thousand of queries.

Comment: How will you know what's broken. The only safe solution has EVER been to make sure every query is properly escape.

Answer (score 2):

Turn it off. The pain of recoding by hand, case by case, pales compared to the agony of being hacked.

Answer (score 1):

[See here click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520298/6194547)

This is the method I use. If you are using case method switch, simply connect the index.php file. ***second method, you need to add to each page.***

> 1. index.php?page=home
> 2. index.php?page=two ...

**SECOND METHOD ADD CODE PER PAGE**

> 1. index.php
> 2. contact.php
> 3. product.php ....

Recommended : simple page query case / switch

```
// Magic Quotes Fix
if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    function clean($data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[clean($key)] = clean($value);
            }
        } else {
            $data = stripslashes($data);
        }

        return $data;
    }           

    $_GET = clean($_GET);
    $_POST = clean($_POST);
    $_REQUEST = clean($_REQUEST);
    $_COOKIE = clean($_COOKIE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can,  but don't forget that you can also send arrays via GPC.  `?var[1]=data`.  It should be noted that magic_quotes_gpc was removed for a damn good reason and I bet many beers that your application is highly vulnerable to sql injection.

```
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function my_escape(&$value, $key) {$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);}
    $gpc = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    array_walk_recursive($gpc, 'my_escape');
}
```

Comment: Escaping all the globals for MySQL use may not be appropriate.

Comment: @stillstanding  yep,  and it won't stop all sql injection.

Comment: Why wouldn't it stop an attack?

Comment: @Juddling Many many reasons.  2 most common,  you aren't using quote marks around the variable in your query,  or you use a decode function like urldecode()  base64_decode() html_entity_decode() or even substring().   In short,  this is the worst way to attempt to defend against sql injection.   If you do go with that code i posted,  you should sign up for a free vulnerability scanning service like http://sitewat.ch,  it will be able find the gaps.