# How can i prevent sql injection but keep " and '?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection, html-entities

How do prevent sql injection in php but still show " and '? A the moment I am using

```
$input = strip_tags($input);
$input = htmlentities($input);
```

However the output is \" and \'. Is there anyway I can show " and ' without the slashes but keep them there so I don't get injected?

Comment: Replace ' with '' (two times single quote), before executing command to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that code is not stripping backslashes, of course they're still there. Use stripslashes() to take out backslashes, but DON'T DO IT. 
If you see those slashes in the DB, and you HAVE USED mysql_real_escape_string, chances are you have magic_quotes_gpc on, and you're just adding another set of slahses. Remove those auto added first and then apply mysql_real_escape_string, they won't show this way but will still be there and make for a safe use in querying your DB.

Comment: I just added this to the htaccess file: php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

Answer (score 5):

The method you show is not a proper way to protect against SQL injection!

Always use the sanitation method provided by the database library you are using, e.g. [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) if you work with the standard mysql library. The sanitation method will not alter any characters in the end result.

Alternatively, use prepared statements in PDO or mysqli - those do input sanitation automatically if you bind the incoming data correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that. Do I only need to do this for when inserting/deleting things in mysql?

Comment: @Cameron yes, that sanitation method is mysql specific. There are other things you need to do e.g. when outputting data in a HTML page or sending them as E-Mail but this specific thing is for mysql only.

Comment: So, if I want to echo these before I put them into my database is it okay to leave out mysql_real_escape_string untill I insert the data? It is showing \\\' now and \\\" for some reason!

Comment: do you have to use mysql as a database link for mysql_real_escape_string or can you use odbc links too? Thanks

Comment: @Cameron you may have magic quotes turned on - check them out and turn them off if necessary @Drewdin ODBC? No, as said, `mysql_real_escape_string` is for the `mysql_*` family of functions only. Every database wrapper has its own sanitation functions if necessary

Comment: I'm not sure if I can, I use a free webhost. How would I do this?

Comment: @Cameron and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting

Comment: @Pekka, thanks for the info, i figured that but i have an application where im connecting to odbc connection and i wanted to sanitize the input. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Drewdin what database wrapper are you using? There should be something on sanitation in the manual, and there probably is something on the topic on SO.

Comment: @Pekka Im a rookie so im not sure what a wrapper is, i am connecting to a sybase db on a windows box to query some data. I'll check the manual, thanks!

Comment: @Drewdin "wrapper" means the database library you use to connect to the database. If you're unsure, ask a separate question about it, showing some code - somebody will definitely be able to tell you whether what you do is safe or not.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of  prepared statements.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
OR
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic solution for being careless.

Also those slashes alone don't prevent SQL injections. The presence of them indicates another problem, magic_quotes. Magic quotes were a convenience feature in PHP2, never intended as security function. (Well accidentially they were secure around 1997 when databases didn't support multibyte charsets).

Anyway, disable magic_quotes. Use manual escaping (mysql_real_escape_string) or better yet the much more convenient prepared statements with PDO.

If you want to be lazy, disable magic_quotes still. But use `$_GET = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_GET);` and do the same for $_POST and $_REQUEST at the start of your scripts and after the database connection was established.
And then apply `htmlentities(stripslashes($input))` for writing output to ge rid of the extraneous backslashes.

Comment: @Cameron: It's a setting in the `php.ini`. You can change it via .htaccess if you follow the `php_value` tip in the comment here http://php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: I use shared hosting, is it possible?

Comment: @Cameron: You'll have to test it. It works with mod_php servers. With a FastCGI setup you would have to install or modify a personal `php.ini`