# Android JSON with PHP, characters with accent not being handled properly

Tags: java, php, android, json

In a nutshell, french characters are causing trouble when sending string from my android app to php and decoding it using JSON.
Here is what I am doing in my android app (Java)

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(//my server and filename);

    try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("payload", jsonObj.toString()));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

       // Execute HTTP Post Request
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     }....
```

And here is my php code

```
$_POST['payload'] = stripslashes($_POST['payload']); 
$payload = $_POST['payload'];
error_log(" $payload ", 0);
$payloadObj = json_decode($payload);
error_log(" $payloadObj ", 0);
```

When english letters are used then everything is perfect, however is perfect but when  I accented frensh letters then it does not work. I inserted the above Error logs to see what I get and I noticed that with French letters, payload is showing the french letter as � 
and the payloadObj is empty so I guess the decode failed.

Pleeease help me out,where is exactly the problem happening (at what stage)? How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you using `stripslashes()`?

Comment: Because I am using this info  for mysql and it is the in case magicQuotes is on. It didnt do any harm with english letters

Comment: `stripslashes()` does **nothing** for MySQL, and has nothing at all to do with it.  You should disable magic quotes.  If you can't, check this answer out:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/517027/362536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had you try fix it using iconv() ?

```
//$payload = $_POST['payload'];
$payload = (isset($_POST['payload'])) ? iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$_POST['payload']) ? '';
error_log(" $payload ", 0);
$payloadObj = json_decode($payload);
error_log(" $payloadObj ", 0);
```

Comment: I will accept the answer just because it gave me hint about the correct solution. The correct solution is to do httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs), "UTF-8"); and that fixed it