# Cannot save article in Joomla 3.0 Magic Quotes issue

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am unable to save any article  /  module etc in Joomla 3.0. When I try to save the `" "` is replaced by `"\&quot;\&quot;"`. This messes up all my code. I tried turning off the `magic_quotes_gpc` in php.ini but that did not help.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I presume you did the Joomla! 3 installation by adding the .htaccess with magic_quotes_gpc = off inside the install directory, to successfully install the platform, correct?

If your server is running php 5.3+ you need to **set the server php configuration** to magic_quotes_gpc = off. It should be configured as so since magic_quotes_gpc is deprecated in php 5.3 and will be removed in 5.4.

In summary, you can only overcome this issue by configuring the php on the server. No .htaccess will solve your problem, unless you place an .htaccess inside each and every directory on your Joomla! installation - which is unthinkable imo.

Comment: I don't have access to the php.ini file. I tried adding magic_quotes_gpc=off within the .htaccess file. However, that gave me a 500 internal server error. Any workaround for doing it with the .htaccess?

Comment: The workaround is to contact your provider and ask them to set the magic_quotes_gpc to off in the server php configuration. As I mentioned, if you're running on a php 5.3+ server, the function should be off by default.

Answer (score 0):

fixing the issue where adding `\&quot;` during article posts in administrator panel:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Disable these options from your php.ini file.

You can also overwrite the php.ini.

Please check the link for overwriting the php.ini using .htaccess

[How to turn off magic quotes on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting/10533989#10533989)