# Converting a stringified json structure to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, serialization, stringify

I'm saving a cookie with json data. Example of echo `$_COOKIE['data']`

> [{\"date\":1355249777,\"title\":\"junior\"},{\"date\":1355249747,\"title\":\"christopher\"},{\"date\":1355249139,\"title\":\"melfi\"},{\"date\":1355249123,\"title\":\"tony\"},{\"date\":1355248876,\"title\":\"carmela\"},{\"date\":1355248859,\"title\":\"meadow\"}]

The data was pure javascript, then passed by `JSON.stringify` and then stored in the cookie. Now i need to convert it to a php array. I tried a `json_decode` approach but it returns null. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: if you use `JSON.stringify` before passing it to php, `json_decode()` should be all you need. can we see more of your code?

Comment: it appears you need to stripslashes().

Comment: I think json_decode is having hard time understanding your current structure because of the slashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off magic quotes on shared hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting)

Comment: yes, it seems the slashes were interfering with json_decode()

Comment: I don't think that really is a duplicate of that other quesiton.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

`json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE['data']));`

Comment: The the square bracket enclosure also needs to be stripped.

Comment: @Lenin i didn't get your point. anyway here is working sample: http://codepad.org/XX9QD3iX

Comment: Yeah, this was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

a small fix to the answer above (can't comment yet)...

```
json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE['data']),true);
```

otherwise you may get [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) error