# When saving ' to database, i get \' in a text box

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am learning PDO after the many people telling me to do so. However in updating one of my scripts, PDO is causing me a problem that I'm not sure how to fix.

My problem is a user will input the title to the website. Say its "Smith's Inventory".

Since the whole PDO switch, it is saved in the db as "Smith\'s Inventory". Which is output in various places on my website. Such as the header, the html title, and the settings text box. If you click save again with \', then you get \\', and so on.

I realize why this is done, but how can it be fixed?

Here is the instert code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE settings set value=? where variable=?");
    $sql->bindParam(1, $value);
    $sql->bindParam(2, $key);
    $sql->execute();
}
echo '<h2><font  color=green>Saved</font></h2>';
```

Comment: Do you have magic quotes enabled?

Comment: Please show the code that you are using to insert data into the database.  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.

Comment: Magic quotes has to be the dumbest idea ever implemented.

Comment: @bobwienholt — register_globals gives them a run for their money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stripslashes` on the PHP side.

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

Comment: It is better to solve the actual issue instead of trying a work around

Comment: Well after doing a little research, there is not a universal way to turn off magic quoted. Would stripslashes need to be put before the insert into mysql or after the fetch from mysql?

Comment: @alexander7567 After the fetch. `stripslashes` would wrap the variable  coming out of your query.

Comment: Well since this is going to be used in many different enviroments, this seemed like the best choice. However, I am still open for suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are double escaping the data.

The most likely reasons for this are:

- Your PHP install has magic quotes enabled — [best to turn them off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting)
- You are using something like mysql_real_escape_string **and** prepared statements with placeholders — use only the latter

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before, it was due to PHP magic quotes. PHP automatically inserts a slash to escape 'risky' characters in order to prevent sql injection.

You need to either disabled magic quotes on your php install or use the stripstashes function just before you output it.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php
```

You can read about magic quotes here:

```
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-magic-quotes.php
```