# Php backslashes Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I've a html form which handle by Php. When I submit the form it's show a backslashes if i write for example: **5 rue de l'ourq**. If a again submit the form because of I wrongly input any other field of the form then it's show **5 rue de l\'ourq** and again **5 rue de l\\'ourq**. This is happened in **address** filed.

**Php Variable:**

```
$address = $_POST['address'];   
$title = inputvalid($_POST['title']);   
$f_name = inputvalid($_POST['f_name']);
```

The problem is $address variable. I don't why it's show the backslashes. That's why I didn't put **inputvalid** function to that variable but can't fix this. Any idea ?

Comment: Check `magic_quotes_gpc` option in your php.ini file and set it to `Off`. My answer is below.

Comment: Perhaps the [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function, so you need [stripslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) also

Comment: there probably is an issue in your character escaping prior to database insertion. Using prepared statements would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your config file:

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', 'off');
```

OR, if this is not allowed on your server, put this in config:

```
##/ Special Code to stop get_magic_quotes_gpc
function stop_magic_quotes($in)
{
    $out = $in;

    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        if(is_array($out))
        {
            foreach($out as $k=>$v)
            {
                $v = stop_magic_quotes($v);
                $out[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $out = stripslashes($out);
        }
    }

    return $out;
}//end func................

if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $_GET = array_map('stop_magic_quotes', $_GET);
    $_POST = array_map('stop_magic_quotes', $_POST);
}//end if....
```

Comment: I put this code to my form page. But After submit it it's again show  "5 rue de l\'ourq"

Comment: ok I have edited and added new code there. just make sure your config file gets included before you get your address, title etc.

Comment: did you enter fresh values? like this "5 rue de l'ourq". I think this cant be solved without looking at the code completely.

Comment: put var_dump($address); die(); right below $address=$_POST['address']; then see if the backslash is still there.

Comment: ok... create a "php.ini" file on the root. and put this line in it:

magic_quotes_gpc = Off

Comment: Yes I created the txt file

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you have magic_quotes turned on. You need to turn them off in you php settings.

If you can't turn off magic_quotes, I would make the first thing your `inputvalid()` function does is check to see if magic_quotes are enabled, if they are then `stripslashes()` on values.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

According to link above you can simulate disabling at runtime by adding the following code, but it is really just doing the same thing as I said above, checking if magic_quotes are on then `stripslashes()` on input arrays:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

Comment: Normally no, but you can do it in .htaccess normally though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting

Comment: I put this code in my form page. ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', 'off'); But it's again show "5 rue de l\\\'ourq".

Comment: Right that is why I said "No" you can't do it on form.php you have to do it in .htaccess or on the php.ini file. Look at the link I posted.

Comment: If you are adding it to .htaccess you will need to use a different command, I believe it is `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off`

Comment: Can't really help debugging if "not working" is the only thing you tell us.

Answer (score 0):

PHP adds backslashes to escape the `'` because it would literally mean the opening of a string.

Use `stripslashes()` to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `inputvalid` function is preventing SQL injections which are used to load and modify information from your database. The function escapes `'` and `"` to prevent the injections. Your code should be able to translate those escaped characters back to a human-readable form after loading the information from the database.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment to this question:

Check `magic_quotes_gpc` option in your php.ini file and set it to `Off`. Don't forget to restart the php process. If you don't have a  direct access to the php.ini file, try this:

```
 <?php ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', 'Off'); ?>
```