# magic_quotes_gpc off on sharehosting with $_POST Array

Tags: php

It's pain in the *** with magic quote on on the share server, and I am giving up on upload another php.ini to overwrite the share host php.ini, because then other problem occurr, (PDO in configure but not loaded and ect) I tried .htaccess which give a 500 error.

so i have found this solution is pretty good and works well
[How to turn off magic quotes on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting)

```
if ( in_array( strtolower( ini_get( 'magic_quotes_gpc' ) ), array( '1', 'on' ) ) )
{
    $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
    $_GET = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_GET );
    $_COOKIE = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_COOKIE );
}
```

Until i start to post array to the server

```
<select name="gropu[]">
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="2">1</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

then i have the following errro

```
Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in index.php on line 18
```

Please help me on this, it really annoying me while developing something ok on the localhost and once upload to the server it just all wrong...

Comment: Also note, that `parse_str` function depends on magic quotes option, so you have to unquote them on the result if you are using that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually run this on initialization:

```
// attempt to disable 'magic quotes' at runtime
@ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);
@ini_set('magic_quotes_sybase', 0);

// strip slashes if that didn't work
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  function _strip_slashes_ref(&$var){
    $var = stripslashes($var);
  }

  array_walk_recursive($_POST,    '_strip_slashes_ref');
  array_walk_recursive($_GET,     '_strip_slashes_ref');
  array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE,  '_strip_slashes_ref');
  array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, '_strip_slashes_ref');
}
```

Magic quotes are removed in 5.4, so you might want to do this only if:

```
version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') < 0
```

Comment: Really? you can kill it in the runtime? yeah i think the share host that i am using is less than 5.4 -_- Thanks for the help mate

Comment: [Apparently you can't](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). `magic_quotes_runtime` can be disabled on runtime though

Comment: `array_map` applies the callback to the first level only