# magic quotes joomla3 sunddely appears

Tags: joomla

I have a big problem with my joomla 3.0. I have a proyect in 3.0 averything work fine, but sunddely when I insert html code in my page I see a "\" after  my quotation marks

like this

```
<div class=\"row-fluid\">
    <div class=\"span4 principal\">
        <h3>About</h3>
```

If I errase and save, their appears again.

in my php.init I have magic_quotes_gpc= Off

but in my phpInfo() appear on..

I change my .htaccess in my project too

any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixing the issue where adding `\&quot;` during article posts in administrator panel:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Disable these options from your php.ini file.

You can also overwrite the php.ini.

Please check the link for overwriting php.ini using .htaccess.

[How to turn off magic quotes on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting/10533989#10533989)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your server configuration you may have multiple `.htaccess` and/or `php.ini` files in the various directories. They may turn off magic quotes in your frontend, but not in the backend as an example. So check if you have turned off magic quotes in each file.

Or it's just a setting in your editor to escape the quotes.

Comment: thanks @Bakual I have mu own server in local and my phpinfo() say that  i have my php.init in etc .. so I change there I restart apache but I still magic_quotes_gpc= On...a ny idea why dont change

Comment: are you refering to the phpinfo within your Joomla Backend?

Comment: Check for additional php.ini files and .htaccess files. Those in server root, Joomla root and Joomla administration directory are of interest.
Also check the phpinfo for `Configuration File (php.ini) Path `, `Loaded Configuration File`, `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` and `Additional .ini files parsed` and check the files/folders mentioned there.