# Output is showing the escaped quotation marks

Tags: php, pdo

After blinding params and insert data into the database, the quotaion are escaped to be `\"` so the output will looks ugly like : `hello this is an output test \"test \"` 
how to make the quotation marks show normally ?

here is how i insert data to DB.

```
if( $_POST )
{
   include "db.php";

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    if(strlen($title) >= 77) { die('large_title'); };
    if(strlen($content) <= 19) { die('low_content'); };
    if(empty($title)) { $title = 'EMPTY00'; }

 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO na_posts(title,content) VALUES (?, ?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("ss",$title,$content);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();

      $content = htmlspecialchars(mb_substr($content, 0, 125,'utf-8'));
      echo $content.'...';
} else { die('error'); }
```

here is my outputting code:

```
$content = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row->content));
echo $content;
```

Comment: Check the setting of `magic_quotes_gpc` in your PHP config.

Comment: I think two times escaped.

Comment: @CBroe so it's a server configurations side issue ?

Comment: @ArunKillu but how?  blind param is called only once..

Comment: what is your php server version if less than 5.4?check `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())`

Comment: @ArunKillu `if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) echo 'great its working';` and yes get_magic_quotes seems to be working.

Comment: @ArunKillu PHP Version 5.3.24

Comment: @CBroe i tested magic_quotes and it seems to be working.

Comment: tell your host provider to shitch off it its depreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some code that is adding unnecessary slashes when you're inserting data in database.

It's either magic_quotes or some sort of addslashes()/mysql_real_escape_string() somewhere in the code. **Get rid of either of them.**

Comment: None of them exist, i only used OPD blind_param to escape string. i duple checked again and the inserting is the only code you can see in the question.

Comment: Well go check again. You know, there is no magic in this world and no slashes can pop out of nowhere.

Comment: @Alamri how come "none of them exist" if you have said in the other comments `"yes get_magic_quotes seems to be working"`?!

Comment: none of `addslashes()/mysql_real_escape_string()` exist. and yes get_magic_quotes is working.... please check my question i updated it with full code.

Comment: i think i should tell my hoster he should feel bad for his PHP configurations.

Comment: @Alamri **it is magic quotes what you need to get rid of**. you can do it yourself, without asking any hoster

Comment: @YourCommonSense for a while i thought magic is exist in webroot :) i already added in php.ini and htaccess the command to disable it but it seems not working that's why my hoster should feel lot of shame :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense trust me that what i did, but i went into a loop of complications one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting and the best solution is getting my own server. anyway thanks for the help. and thanks for comming back and try to help me again, that not what most of users do here.

Comment: @Alamri **please** no silly excuses. There is a link with a **code snippet** which you **obviously able to run** to get rid of magic quotes without altering any server settings. So, it's apparently feasible for the **any** server.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i'm not being silly, i was in the link you gave me before, i did wrote that commands in php.ini , i modified htaccess and got 500 error then i tried the soultion in the question i gave to you(POST,GET,COOKIE). and that's it. no luck. the last chance is contacting them to see what going on or i'm leaving. i'm using stripslashes for now until i find a solution.

Comment: @Alamri look, here is [direct link to the code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php#example-344). This is a **regular PHP code** that have to be put not in php.ini, not in .htaccess but in your PHP script.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i might showed as a stupid in this question but i know where to put the php code :) that's why i said i will use `stripslashes` because i'm using it now and it's working ... but it will be good if i have the ability to configure the php the way i want.

Comment: @Alamri there is the difference *where* to use stripslashes.

Answer (score 1):

use `stripslashes`

```
$content = nl2br(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($row->content)));
echo $content;
```

Comment: YourCommonSense is right, you should solve the actual problem, not circumvent it.