# magic quotes creating problems

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have in shared server `magic_quotes_gpc` is on. I have tried adding the following code to my `.htaccess` file.

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

When I use the above line in `.htaccess`, it throws 500 internal server error.

Even I've tried using `ini_set`  too.

The problem is with CKEEditor. It addslashes the double quotes. And the editor is not woeking properly. I have gone through several answers also but not getting the answer properly.

Please guide me.

PHP Version: 5.3.24

Comment: have you tried turning this off in `php.ini`

Comment: no. as its shared server

Comment: ok please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting

Comment: so I need to use stripslashes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), the `magic_quotes_gpc` directive is [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) so you should be able to change it.

Whenever you see a "500 Internal Server Error" status code in your live server you should head to the log files and find out the exact reason (rather than guessing). Whatever, I suspect that Apache is complaining that the `php_flag` directive is unknown. If that's the case, your PHP interpreter is *not* running as Apache module, thus you cannot use Apache files to change it.

Since your hosting account seems to be pretty old, you'll probably have a custom `php.ini` file somewhere in your FTP account.

Comment: With change in custom php.ini, solved my issue. thanks all of you

Answer (score 2):

If you can't disable magic quotes by *any means*, use the example code from the PHP manual as a workaround to strip the extra slashes: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

Comment: That snippet (and this question all together) has already been [copied/pasted into enough answers](https://www.google.com/#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22%24process+%3D+array(%26%24_GET%2C+%26%24_POST%2C+%26%24_COOKIE%2C+%26%24_REQUEST)%3B%22).. we don't need to continue duplicating it.