# how to turn off magic quotes in .htaccess file for joomla?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magic-quotes-gpc

I started using Joomla 3 and now have problems and on searching i found that magic quotes need to be off for it to function correctly.

I put these lines in the .htaccess file

```
php_value magic_quotes 0
php_flag magic_quotes off
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

and Now I am getting Internal Server Error..

how to disable magic quotes in .htaccess file

Comment: check your Apache error.log to see what the error is.

Comment: Are you using shared or dedicated server? anyway here is a PHP work-around http://stackoverflow.com/a/520298/736564

Comment: If you host in on a serious hoster, it should be off already. It's also deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and removed in PHP 5.4.0. Upload a file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and check if it is on first.

Answer (score 0):

in setup.php, change the code:

```
// Check for magic quotes gpc.
$option = new stdClass;
$option->label  = JText::_('INSTL_MAGIC_QUOTES_GPC');
$option->state  = (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc') == true);
$option->notice = null;
$options[] = $option;
```

you see, force set to true.... then jol can be install done

Answer (score 0):

Create a php.ini or php5.ini file with the following:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Put it in your Joomla 3 root. Then change the htaccess.txt in your Joomla 3 root to .htaccess. Add the following lines to the .htaccess file (at the top), don't forget to change php.ini to php5.ini when applicable :

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
  suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myusername/public_html/yourJ3folder
  <Files php.ini>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
  </Files>
</IfModule>
```

note: dont forget to change suPHP_ConfigPath with your path

reference from https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_turn_off_magic_quotes_gpc_for_Joomla_3