# How to turn off magic quotes gpc for Joomla 3?

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I want to turn off PHP's magic quotes. I don't have access to php.ini.

Without this I am not able to install joomla 3.x.x into server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **For MAMP**

Steps:

1. Go to `MAMP application >> Preferences (button) >> PHP (tab) >> Choose 5.3.1 or greater >> choose OK`.
2. Go to the `MAMP folder >> bin >> php >> php5.3.26 >> conf >> edit php.ini >> add "magic_quotes_gpc = Off"` a few lines above `"magic_quotes_sybase = Off"`.
3. Restart MAMP's servers.

---

## **For most mainstream hosting companies running a CGI-Webinterface**

Steps:

Create a `php.ini` or `php5.ini` file with the following:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Put it in your Joomla 3 root. Then change the `htaccess.txt` in your Joomla 3 root to `.htaccess`. Add the following lines to the `.htaccess` file (at the top), don't forget to change `php.ini` to `php5.ini` when applicable :

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
  suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myusername/public_html/yourJ3folder
  <Files php.ini>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
  </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Change "`myusername`" and "`yourJ3folder`" to your respective folders. The "`/home/myusername/public_html/yourJ3folder`" can be found via the Global Configuration:

In `Joomla backend > System > System Information > [Directory Permissions]`, the folder is usually the same as the log directory (but without /logs at the end).

---

## **.htaccess for some hosts**

For some hosts, add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root of your site (for example `/home/myusername/public_html/.htaccess`)

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

---

## Yet Another Solution For Shared Hosts

create a `php.ini` file at your Joomla! root.
Add this content to the file and save

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Edit your `.htaccess` file and add this line at the top and save the file

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/youruser/public_html/php.ini
```

Test if the error message goes away

source : [How to turn off magic quotes on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting)

---

## Another solution (for the hosts where PHP is running as FCGI module)

Works for PHP 5.3 and higher

create a `.user.ini` file at your Joomla! root.
Add this content to the file and save

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

---

[SRC - https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_turn_off_magic_quotes_gpc_for_Joomla_3](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_turn_off_magic_quotes_gpc_for_Joomla_3)

Answer (score 0):

**From PHP documentation** - http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

The magic_quotes_gpc directive may only be disabled at the system level, and not at runtime. In otherwords, use of ini_set() is not an option.

**BUT**

If access to the server configuration is unavailable, use of .htaccess is also an option. For example:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```