# Why is my form inserting backslashes before quotes?

Tags: php, html, magic-quotes-gpc, magic-quotes

My php code to edit a text document is adding a backslash anywhere a ' or a " is used and I can't figure out why. Anybody ever ran into this before? How did you fix it?

```
<? 
if($_POST['Submit']){ 
$open = fopen("../content.txt","w+"); 
$text = $_POST['update']; 
fwrite($open, $text); 
fclose($open); 
echo "File updated.<br />";  
echo "File:<br />"; 
$file = file("../content.txt"); 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text."<br />"; 
} 
}else{ 
$file = file("../content.txt"); 
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">"; 
echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">"; 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text; 
}  
echo "</textarea>"; 
echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n 
</form>"; 
} 
?>
```

So when I type for instance

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
```

It saves looking like this

```
<a href=/"index.php/">Home</a>
```

[image: Output]

[image: After save]

Comment: Your text editor or PHP is adding the slashes? If PHP you must be using an older version with magic quotes on.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm still kinda new to PHP. I added pictures of what it's doing so you all could see tho.

Comment: Yea, that is magic quotes in that case. There are many threads on how to disable that. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting

Depending on who you are allowing to comment like this you also might be open to XSS injections.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks a lot!